# Add @PathParam to an already existing string

Tags: java, string

i have a string like this:

```
EmpDetails retrieveEmpInformation(String s1, String s2, String s3) // note here it can be any number of paramteters
```

and now I want that string to be like this:

```
EmpDetails retrieveEmpInformation(@PathParam("s1")String s1, @PathParam("s2")String s2, @PathParam("s3")String s3);
```

what is the easiest way to do this. currently i am doing lot of if statements.

Comment: copy and paste or reflection

Comment: Or use a big delimited String and split.

Comment: hi i didn't get you. reflection works only on class files right not on strings?

Comment: relfection also works on methods, fields, etc